# Django - How to fix model with id field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I unintentionally created a model with a field "id" and did the migration. The model at first looked like this:

```
class VsSession(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(default="123"),
    state = models.CharField(choices=VSSESSION_CHOICES, default='dead', max_length=10)
```

Afterwards I rename the field to vs_session:

```
class VsSession(models.Model):
    vs_session = models.TextField(default="123"),
    state = models.CharField(choices=VSSESSION_CHOICES, default='dead', max_length=10)
```

Now whenever I try to use the model e.g., like this:

```
def get(self, request):
    try:
        sessionid = uuid.uuid4()
        new_session = VsSession(vs_session=sessionid, state="active")
        new_session.save()

        return Response({'success': 'true', 'vssession': sessionid})
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return Response({'success': 'false'})
```

I get this error:

```
VsSession() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vs_session'
```

Can anybody please tell me what I did wrong and how to fix this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have no idea why this is working now, but I fixed it. What I did is

1. Removed vs_session variable from the model
2. Added created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) to the model
3. makemigration and migrate
4. Run code/stop code
5. Add vs_session variable to model
6. makemigration an migrate
7. Everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `python manage.py makemigrations`? After running this you should see a message telling you the field was renamed. To actually apply the migration to your database you can run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes - I actually did this multiple times, keeps telling me that there are no changes to migrate.

Comment: It might be a name conflict with `vs_session` and something Django has under the hood. Try renaming to something that does not have vs session in it. Other than that the only other thing I can think of is making sure your models.py file is saved

Comment: Also perhaps try: `VsSession.objects.filter(vs_session='something').first()`

Comment: I tried to rename vs_session to something different but when trying to do the migration I just get "No changes detected" which is not correct. When trying to create an object of the model I still get "VsSession() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sim_session'". sim_session is the new name of vs_session.